# Spock spy causes "MethodMissingException"

Tags: groovy, spock

I am trying to do a partial mock using Spock Spy.
Here is code that works:

```
setup:
Bulk bulk = new Bulk()
bulk.setApi(stub)           
when:
bulk.updateHeldBounsedSubscribers(subscribers, bounceEvents)
```

and here is the code that does not work:

```
setup:
Bulk bulk = Spy(Bulk)
bulk.getSubscribersByKeys(_) >> subs
bulk.setApi(stub)           
when:
bulk.updateHeldBounsedSubscribers(subscribers, bounceEvents)
```

It produces following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.otpp.email.BulkEmailDownloader$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8227f19f.updateHeldBounsedSubscribers() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerapi.Subscriber@57a41eae], ...]
at com.otpp.email.DownloaderUnitTests.updateHeldBounsedSubscribers test with mocked API objects(DownloaderUnitTests.groovy:223)
```

Comment: Is `updateHeldBounsedSubscribers` a public method? What's line 223?

Comment: It was private. I changed it to protected and it works. Now the problem is that the original "getSubscribersByKeys" method seems to be called even though I tried to replace it with a stubbed method.

Comment: Ok, now everything works. Thank you. If you post your recommendation as an answer I will accept it. You might also mention that the method that is being stubbed also needs to be accessible (protected or public)

Comment: @DaSh you add an answer on your own and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method was private. 
I changed it to protected and it works.